# IE - status bar shows loading continuously

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, portable-areas

I have an razor MVC page - It is loaded via MVC Portable Areas.
When i browse to the index action, everything loads fine, and works as expected.

...But occasionally Internet Explorer continually shows the loading bar in the status bar. The loading never completes, but the page functionality works fine (so it must have loaded all my  resources)

I can't replicate this in firefox, and i have checked the Net tab on firebug to look for slow loading resources, but everything looks fine.

I want to try and cause the loading bar to stop after a set time (i know this could be masking a problem, but i can't seem to find out what is going wrong with the page!!)
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Check with fiddler and see what requests are being made in IE

Comment: I forgot about fidder! i'll give that a try now, IE developer tools are just useless!

Answer (score 0):

IE does that sometimes. Like you said, there is no actual issues except for the loadfing bar being shown.

To confirm that everything is OK, put an `alert("loaded")` in your `$(document).ready();`. If it alerts you, the page was successfully loaded and it's just IE being a buggy little... bugger.

Edit: I missed a bit. Continued:

This is ofcourse only the case if you do not have ajax calls etc on the page that can start a loading sequence after the document has loaded. In that case, use the debugger to check for open connections.

Comment: all my javascript is being loaded correctlt, i am using an ajax request but that is performed on a button click, I forgot about using fiddler, I'm going to give that a try to see if there are any lengthy requests. I just hate the IE developer tools!!!

Comment: Yep. I always use Chrome's debugger. That would be very easy here as you can instantly see if there is an open request in the Net tab. I've never used Fiddler as I've never needed anything else other that what Chrome provides. Let me know how it goes.